# Variable length objects and using traditional for loop

Tags: java

In one of my methods, I need to pass objects as variable length parameters.
However, first I need to process the last object and then based on that many other processing will be done. I could not figure out how to use the index for each of the items in the variable argument list using traditional for loop and then index. So I used below code. Is this the right method to copy the object reference to another Array or ArrayList as I did? Otherwise what is the best method to access the specific object first and then loop through all other objects.

```
 public static int generateConnectedPatterns(String endStr,Moorchana.MoorchanInnerClass...totalPatterns) {


// First copy all the objects to new ArrayList or Array of objects
            ArrayList <Moorchana.MoorchanInnerClass> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
            objectList.addAll(Arrays.asList(totalPatterns));
            //Temporarily use lastObject variable for convenience.
            Moorchana.MoorchanInnerClass lastObject = objectList.get(objectList.size()-1);      
            // Split the last input string into swaras
            ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> tempPatternList = new ArrayList<>();

        splitInputPatternIntoArrayList(tempPatternList , indices, lastObject.rawInputString);

         if (Moorchana.validatePresenceInSwaraPool(endStr, lastObject.returnOuterObjectRef().swaraPool) == -1) {
            return (-1);
        }

         // Get the index of the ending String
         int indexofEndStr = lastObject.returnOuterObjectRef().getSwaraIndex(endStr);
         // Now get the number of patterns to be generated.
         int count = lastObject.returnOuterObjectRef().getPatternCount(indices, indexofEndStr);


         // Now Do remaining programming here based on the count.


        return(Constants.SUCCESS);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. `Moorchana.MoorchanInnerClass...totalPatterns`is the same as `Moorchana.MoorchanInnerClass[] totalPatterns`: totalPatterns is a Java array. You access the element at index i using `totalPatterns[i]`. And you access the length of the array using `totalPatterns.length`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

Treat `totalPatterns`  as an array.

To identify the last element: `totalPatterns[totalPatterns.length-1]`

for iteration, you could use an enhanced for loop.

```
for ( Moorchana.MoorchanInnerClass d : totalPatterns){...}
```

**Note**: Do a null check before you process the array, if you are not sure of the input being passed.

Answer (score 2):

A varargs is basically an `array`.

Once you checked for `null` and `length`, you can access the last element just as you would with an `array`.

On the other hand, `Arrays.asList` returns a **fixed-size** list, which means you will not be able to manipulate its size later on, so beware of `UnsupportedOperationException`s.

In short, you can use the varargs as `array` and reference the last element once the necessary checks are performed.

Comment: OK, I got it. I actually wanted to call generateConnectedPatterns() by dynamically creating objects something like: generateConnectedPatterns("Test1", mayamalavagowla.arohaObj.new MoorchanInnerClass("S1,,R2,,G3",""), mayamalavagowla.arohaObj.new MoorchanInnerClass("D2,,P1,"")); I will now create ArrayList in calling portion and then pass that array list